# Expectation of the product of two independent random vectors and a positive-definite matrix

Tags: econometrics, expected-value, independence, linear-algebra, quadratic-form

I am trying to compute the following: $\mathbb{E}[X^T\Omega^{-1}\epsilon]$, where $X$ is a  random matrix, $\epsilon$ is a random vector, $\Omega$ is a real positive-definite matrix, and $\mathbb{E}[X^T\epsilon]=0$ (since each row of $X$ is independent from each row of $\epsilon$, and $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon]=0)$.

I conjecture that $\mathbb{E}[X^T\Omega^{-1}\epsilon]=0$ as well, as a linear transformation of independent random vectors is also independent. Is this correct?

Comment: Which probability distribution is the expectation applied with respect to?

Comment: The [trace trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228398/trace-trick-for-expectations-of-quadratic-forms) is potentially relevant here, but as @mhdadk points out, you do have to specify what the expectation is over first and check if this still applies.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation is zero, using that expectation and trace commutes (what some calles the trace trick), and the cyclic property of the trace operator.
$$   \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}  \DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}  
\E \left[ X^T\Omega^{-1}\epsilon \right]= \\
\Tr \E \left[ X^T\Omega^{-1}\epsilon \right]= \\
\E \Tr \left[ X^T\Omega^{-1}\epsilon \right]= \\
\E \Tr \left[ \Omega^{-1}\epsilon X^T \right]= \\ 
\Omega^{-1} \E \Tr \left[ \epsilon X^T \right]= \\ 
\Omega^{-1} \E \Tr \left[ X^T \epsilon \right]= \\ 
\Omega^{-1} \E 0= 0.
$$

Comment: You don't need to go to such lengths.  The original expression is *explicitly* a linear combination (as given by the matrix $X^\prime\Omega^{-1}$) of zero-mean variables (the vector $\epsilon$.)  A full answer, then, is "the value conditional on $X$ is zero by linearity of expectation and therefore the unconditional expectation is zero, too."  The problem with the trace approach is that it's nonsensical: $X^\prime\Omega^{-1}\epsilon$ isn't necessarily a square matrix.